# How can i dock an asp.net: table to my web page so it (the table dock) dynamically adjusts to browser width?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

1. My Problem:

I have a fluid CSS design layout that works brilliantly, albeit until **my asp.net: table** messes things up! When the user reduces the browser size or if the user is logged on via a mobile device my table will extend itself to it's actual width which is approx 1000px.

1. What iv'e tried to do:

Iv'e tried using javascript code to fix this and it works only if i specify the max width but i need a way for this code to know the current max width of the screen

1. My code used:

the script:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

       $('#dvTableDock').width($('#dvPageWidth').width());


    </script>
```

i then create a style:

```
.TableDock
    {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 870px; // Need to dynamically specify width here
        height:200px;
        padding: 0 0 17px 0;
    }
```

i then add a div that gets screen width and apply the style and script to another  tag that wraps the table:

```
<div id="dvScreenWidth" visible="false">
</div>
<div class="TableDock" id="dvTableDock">
 //table in here
</div>
```

What i want is for the dock to know when to show the horizontal scroll, i.e when the screen width becomes less than 1000px and the table begins to extend out of the page.

I really hope i have made my self clear in this question but please let me know what other information is needed to help me. Thanks to anyone that helps or corrects any of my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is my own solution which worked:

```
.TableDock
        {
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: auto;
            //Remove the width and height completely
            padding: 0 0 17px 0;
        }
```

I solved this by removing the width and height completely

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using fixed width (ie, pixels units) use percents.

```
.TableDock
    {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 95%;
        height:200px;
        padding: 0 0 17px 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i solved it by removing the width and height completely :) weird. but thanks for the trying!